# Passing a Mat array from EmguCV to OpenCV?

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, emgucv, mat

I am attempting to send a EmguCV Mat object from C# to a OpenCV C++ DLL function. My original data is in a byte[] array and then I convert it to a Mat object.

I am getting the error on the line that I call my C++ function: Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'Emgu.CV.Mat'

I am not sure how I should be passing my data from the C# code into the C++ function.

Here is my C# code:

```
 private void image_algorithms(byte[] buffer, int width, int height)
        {
            int grid_count = 5;
            int grid_width = width / grid_count;
            int grid_height = height / grid_count;
            MyImage = new Image<Gray, byte>(width, height);
            MyImage.Bytes = buffer;

            Mat image_pre_crop = MyImage.Mat;
            //calling C++ function here
            Mat croppedImage = crop_image(image_pre_crop);

        }
```

My C++ function looks like this:

```
Mat crop_image(Mat image) {

    bool fromCenter = false;
    namedWindow("Crop frame", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    Rect2d r = selectROI("Crop frame", image, fromCenter);
    Mat imgCrop = image(r);

    return imgCrop;

}
```

Comment: As explained in [this answer](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/issues/616), it says *Your native function should return not Mat but Mat**

Comment: Your native function should also accept a Mat * so a pointer to Mat. When calling the native function from within c# you should pass the native pointer such as image_pre_crop.Ptr